# Bluetooth headset sound broke and connection lost after minutes

Tags: bluetooth, headset

The Bluetooth detects my headphones and I can pair it, but the sound is continuously broken and after few minutes de connection is lost.
The only strange thing that I found in the syslog is that the device is detected as a keyboard (even when I can listen using it :D ).

```
Jun 20 18:46:55 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jun 20 18:46:55 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Jun 20 18:46:55 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): device removed
Jun 20 18:46:55 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input38/event24"
Jun 20 18:46:55 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
```

No idea what to do next, so any advice is welcome.

System:

- Headset Bose QuietComfort 35 Series 2
- Bluetooth adapter: `Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0b05:17cb ASUSTek Computer, Inc. Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth`, but it happens exactly the same with my laptop and integrated Bluetooth
- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Full logs:

```
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 27
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) config/udev: removing device Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP)
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "fd" "88"
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): device removed
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:88
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[1165]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  198.066382] kauditd_printk_skb: 268 callbacks suppressed
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  198.066386] audit: type=1107 audit(1592675051.571:374): pid=1171 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="CheckPermissions" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=2844 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1174 peer_label="unconfined"
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  198.066386]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jun 20 18:44:11 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gsd-media-keys[2668]: Unable to get default sink
Jun 20 18:44:14 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[1165]: Control: Refusing unexpected connect
Jun 20 18:44:14 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[1165]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_11_A5_33_E3_30/sep1/fd1: fd(33) ready
Jun 20 18:44:14 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE rtkit-daemon[1554]: Supervising 11 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jun 20 18:44:14 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE rtkit-daemon[1554]: Successfully made thread 5068 of process 2258 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun 20 18:44:14 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE rtkit-daemon[1554]: Supervising 12 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jun 20 18:44:24 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[1165]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Jun 20 18:44:24 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gsd-media-keys[2668]: Unable to get default sink
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE bluetoothd[1165]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_28_11_A5_33_E3_30/sep1/fd2: fd(33) ready
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE rtkit-daemon[1554]: Supervising 11 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE rtkit-daemon[1554]: Successfully made thread 5100 of process 2258 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE rtkit-daemon[1554]: Supervising 12 threads of 2 processes of 2 users.
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  224.273863] input: Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input36
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event24)
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP)'
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1480]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event24)
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1480]: (**) Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1480]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP)'
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event24 13:88 fd 100 paused 0
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): always reports core events
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event24"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): device removed
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input36/event24"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 19)
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb,gb"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "xkb_variant" ",intl"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp_led:scroll"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1480]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event24 13:88 fd 26 paused 1
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1480]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:88
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[2349]: (II) event24 - Mr. Dynamite (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  224.318720] audit: type=1107 audit(1592675077.827:375): pid=1171 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="CheckPermissions" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=2844 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1174 peer_label="unconfined"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  224.318720]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  224.323107] audit: type=1107 audit(1592675077.831:376): pid=1171 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="CheckPermissions" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=2844 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1174 peer_label="unconfined"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  224.323107]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  224.338912] audit: type=1107 audit(1592675077.847:377): pid=1171 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="CheckPermissions" name=":1.10" mask="receive" pid=2844 label="snap.spotify.spotify" peer_pid=1174 peer_label="unconfined"
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE kernel: [  224.338912]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Jun 20 18:44:37 angelcc-B450-AORUS-ELITE gnome-shell[2566]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
```

Comment: do you have the package pulseaudio-module-bluetooth installed ?

Comment: I did not install anything special. Is it in the default installation?

Comment: @kannzzmm2 Yes, it is installed.